# auto populating from column A to B depending on the results in Column B

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to figure out a way to auto populate from one column to another. Once the Numbers are in column A depending on the numbers in column B like this is the logic I'm trying to figure out in code.

If column A is greater than 0 or equal to 25 then column B would write "black" down the columns.

I wasn't able to figure out a solution.

Comment: [`Select Case` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/select-case-statement). Note that this can easily be done with a simple worksheet formula, w/o VBA.

Comment: I'm assuming you mean: if BB is between 0 and 19 then black, if BB is between 20 and 100 ...

Answer (score 0):

Like this? :

`=SWITCH(TRUE,AND(B1>=0,B1<=19),"Black",AND(B1>=20,B1<=99),"Grey",AND(B1>=100,B1<=199),"White","OUT OF RANGE")`

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yeah Exactly like that, But not with the color in column D.

Comment: In your example Column B would be numbers and column C would be text" black", "white" or "Grey"

Comment: Also, is there a way, I'm able to make macro from this? like add that into a macro.?

Comment: 1) I just put in the colors with conditional formatting for the sake of presentation. 2) There is absolutely a way to make a macro for this,  the easiest would be to make a UDF to replace the formula. The next easiest would be to write macro that iterates through the range like `for each cel in My range.cells...` , and fastest would be to do the same with an array.

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem to have an aversion to formulas, here are three ways to do it with macros:

**1) UDF**
Basically just taking the whole formula logic from the previous answer and combining it into one convenient UDF:

```
Option Explicit
Function WhiteGreyBlack(Ref As Range) As String
    
    Dim N As Long
    
    N = CLng(Ref.Value)
    
    Select Case True
        Case N >= 0 And N <= 19
            WhiteGreyBlack = "Black"
        Case N >= 20 And N <= 99
            WhiteGreyBlack = "Grey"
        Case N >= 100 And N <= 199
            WhiteGreyBlack = "White"
        Case Else
            WhiteGreyBlack = "OUT OF RANGE"
    End Select
    
End Function
```

[image: Example 1]

---

**2) Range Looping**
Same exact logical section, we're just iterating through the range and placing results as unchanging values

```
Option Explicit
Sub WhiteGreyBlackRange()
    
    Dim RG As Range
    Dim CL As Range
    Dim OS As Long
    Dim N As Long
    Dim lRow As Long
    
    On Error GoTo ErrorWithRange
    
    Set RG = Application.InputBox( _
        Title:="Select Range", _
        Prompt:="Select the Range of cells to test", _
        Type:=8)
    If RG Is Nothing Then GoTo ErrorWithRange
    If RG.Cells.Count > 3000 Then GoTo ErrorWithRange
    If RG.Columns.Count > 1 Then GoTo ErrorWithRange
    
    On Error GoTo MiscError
    
    OS = Application.InputBox( _
        Title:="Select Offset", _
        Prompt:="Enter how far Offset you want the result:" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
                """+1"" = one column to the right" & vbCrLf & _
                """-3"" = Three columns to the right")
    If OS = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Offset Must not equal 0", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Error"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    For Each CL In RG.Cells
        N = CL.Value
        Select Case True
            Case N >= 0 And N <= 19
                CL.Offset(0, OS).Value = "Black"
            Case N >= 20 And N <= 99
                CL.Offset(0, OS).Value = "Grey"
            Case N >= 100 And N <= 199
                CL.Offset(0, OS).Value = "White"
            Case Else
                CL.Offset(0, OS).Value = "OUT OF RANGE"
        End Select
    Next CL
      
Exit Sub
MiscError:
    MsgBox "Unknown Error", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Error"
Exit Sub
ErrorWithRange:
    MsgBox "Please select only one vertical line of cells, " & vbCrLf & _
            "Please do not select the entire column." & vbCrLf & _
            "Please do not select more than 3000 cells at a time", _
            vbOKOnly + vbCritical, _
            "Error with range selection... "
End Sub
```

---

**3) Array Looping**
Best option for very large data sets.
You could incorporate the same user input and error handling options from the Range looping if you felt the need.

```
Option Explicit
Sub WhiteGreyBlackArray()
    
    Dim RG As Range
    Dim RGOut As Range
    Dim ValArray
    Dim I As Long
    
    Set RGOut = Sheet1.Range("F2:F34")
    Set RG = Sheet1.Range("B2:B34")
    ValArray = RG
    
    For I = 1 To UBound(ValArray, 1)
        Select Case True
            Case ValArray(I, 1) >= 0 And ValArray(I, 1) <= 19
                ValArray(I, 1) = "Black"
            Case ValArray(I, 1) >= 20 And ValArray(I, 1) <= 99
                ValArray(I, 1) = "Grey"
            Case ValArray(I, 1) >= 100 And ValArray(I, 1) <= 199
                ValArray(I, 1) = "White"
            Case Else
                ValArray(I, 1) = "OUT OF RANGE"
        End Select
    Next I
        
    RGOut = ValArray

End Sub
```

---

All 4 are great options:
[image]